# ReportViewer Error in ASPX for Remote SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, reportviewer, ssrs-2008

I get the following error:

> In remote mode, the Report Viewer control requires session state be
>   enabled or Report Server connection information specified in the
>   config file.

`Windows 2008 server`, `IIS 7`, `Dot Net 3.5`

`sessionState=InProc`

After rebooting, I still get the error.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the Report Server connection information setup in the Config file of your webservice?

Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251661.aspx

Working in remote mode, you need to specify the reporting service connection string for report viewer to function.